# Did anybody use numerical analysis before modern computers were introduced?

Tags: numerical-methods, math-history, numerical-optimization, numerical-calculus

I was recently introduced to Numerical analysis to solve PDEs and I was wondering wether this kind of approach was also used barehand to reach approximate conclusions in the same way it is now done by employing calculators.

Comment: Look at https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Fox_Leslie/

Comment: Consult E .T .Whittaker and G. Robinson, _The Calculus of Observations_.

Comment: See as well the very interesting case of Runge, the co-inventor of the Runge-Kutta methods https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Runge/

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3467850) mentionning the book "The history of mathematical Tables from Sumer to Spreadsheet" with different interesting stories, in particular the way tables where computed by hiring a large number of **human computers**.

Comment: See a [1935 review](https://www.nature.com/articles/136458a0) of _Numerical Studies in Differential Equations,_ vol 1, by Levy and Baggot. Volume 2 was supposed to cover PDEs. That's long before electronic computers, though you could have used an adding machine at that time.

Comment: Also see [What was the appeal of numerical analysis before computers?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/5612/321) -- indeed this is more of a history-of-mathematics question than a math question.

Comment: [_A History of Numerical Analysis from the 16th through the 19th Century_](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387902777), by Goldstine.

Answer (score 0):

Gauss calculated the orbit of Ceres

> "... for it is now clearly shown that the orbit of a heavenly body may
> be determined quite nearly from good observations embracing only a few
> days; and this without any hypothetical assumption."

[https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~cherlin/History/Papers1999/weiss.html](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Echerlin/History/Papers1999/weiss.html)

Perhaps this answers your question.